# Can I somehow see what I commented or answered to a question deleted by author?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I received a comment from another user that referred to a comment or answer of mine regarding that user's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52449757/do-gson-type-adapters-apply-to-classes-containing-those-types).

Unfortunately - as you can see if you click the link in question - the question was already deleted when I tried to check what it was related to. I cannot anymore remember what I commented or did I answer to that question.

Comment: I notified the asker of this meta question. They might have had reasons to delete the question (though it seems to be harmless), otherwise might share relevant information.

Comment: I had this same question a few days ago.. It seems like you can't without a user with more privilege than you getting involved.

Comment: Here is at least a screenshot:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IILb.png

Comment: @rene I did not dare, not yet having the 10k privileges for a long time. Is it OK to generally provide a screenshot in cases like this? That is why I chose the indirect way of notifying the person who deleted the question.

Comment: @Yunnosch in general no but if I assume it is asked in good faith and don't expect trouble I offer the screenshot in a comment. But if you write a real answer it should be officially declined. Meh.

Comment: @Yunnosch here is some uber-meta chatter about it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95368/taking-screenshots-of-deleted-answers-on-meta-sites-is-considered-bad-behavior

Comment: @pirho, sorry, I thought you would have a way of seeing my last comment without needing extra assistance. I have undeleted it.

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation of your motives and the link seem in line with what I guessed and feel. Thanks for the insights. I am just being extra careful about tact and discretion in relation to a new privilege - without accusing you. @rene

Comment: I didn't feel being accused @Yunnosch so I guess we're all good then.

Comment: @ordonezalex Np. On my behalf the question can stay deleted I got my answer. Only this case I think it would have been better to edit the question.

Comment: @rene can you _please_ deal with the 1500+ rep notification? The unhandled notification lasting that long is giving me palpitations.

Comment: @roganjosh problem is: if I don't see that green notification with a reasonable number gives me palpitations. So this is now a choice between the health of a few community members and my health. While I all luv u very much, I prefer to put my health first.... ;)

Comment: @rene Please, at least remove the comment with this image then

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Per the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions):

> Deleted questions and answers are always visible to their authors, regardless of the author's reputation.

If you'd *answered* the question, you would still have been able to view your answer (and replies to it, and the question too) even after the question was deleted.

But since you only commented, the question - and its comments - remained invisible to you until the author undeleted it.

Comment: I think not only the answer, but also the question is visible, including their comments (but the other answers are not). I am not sure if this is the exact rule but probably yes.

Comment: getting 10k rep is another way

Comment: The way this works is, you can always see your own deleted posts @peterh. If your post is an answer and the question is deleted, you can *also* see the question (because that's necessary in order for you to see the answer). You don't get to see other answers though. And, if you own the question, you don't get to see answers that were deleted prior to the question being deleted (unless they're your own answers of course).

Comment: Maybe this deserve it's own question, but recently my rep went down 10 points without a notification. I assume a question was deleted that I had answered. How am I supposed to find this question? I was curious what the question was and what my answer was. If I search `user:me is:answer` there are no deleted answers there

Comment: AFAIK only 10k users can search for their deleted answers. You also have the "recently deleted answers" that is available to everyone.